# how to deal with ipmitool sol session which looks frozen

Tags: ipmitool, ipmi

I use `ipmitool` SOL session to get console logs from remote server. Initially session is responsive. If I hit `enter`, I can see login message to remote server like below.

```
[SOL Session operational.  Use ~? for help]                                                                                                                               

<hostname> login:
```

But if I don't hit `enter` after activating session and try to press `enter` or any key, it does not do anything. I can see only this line:

`[SOL Session operational.  Use ~? for help]`

I am not sure if the session becomes frozen or not. I can see help after pressing `~?` but it is not helpful to resolve the issue. I don't see that login message again.

Is there way to generate some logs on this session without shutting off remote server ? And what are the ways to deal with frozen sol sessions ?

**UPDATE**
I create SOL sessions by using this command:

```
ipmitool -I lanplus -U <ipmi-username> -P <ipmi-password> -H <ipmi-ip> sol activate
```

Comment: Hi, have you got any solution of it... I am also facing same issue...